# Python : How to locate current Path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I want to read file from other path and make a copy to my current path.

```
os.system("cd " + Path + r" && git log origin/main > D:\Project\untitled\log.txt")
```

`D:\Project\untitled\log.txt` = path to my code

How to make python locate my code path? eg:

```
codeLocation = {some commands}

os.system("cd " + Path + r" && git log origin/main > " + codeLocation + "\log.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
codeLocation = 'D:\\Project\\untitled\\'
```

Then remove the \ from in front of log.txt in your next line:

```
os.system("cd " + Path + r" && git log origin/main > " + codeLocation + "log.txt")
```

Comment: I want the code to be flexible, if my friends  copy the code and put it anywhere, he still can run the code.

Comment: I already found the answer.
`import os` `cwd = os.getcwd()`